# How to rename unknown filename to new filename

Tags: powershell

There is a file with an unknown name being placed into a folder (name could be `4444444-542323442.txt` or `3234234234.txt` or similar). Whenever it is coming in, the existing one is deleted, therefore there is the only one txt file in the folder all the time.  I would like to change the name to like `newname.txt`.

I tried this:

```
Get-Childitem -Path C:\logsTop1\*.txt |
  Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace ".txt","newname.txt"}
```

but I checked the txt file in the folder the name is like this `3234234234newname.txt`.

It added, I would like to just rename to `newname.txt`.

How can I do that?

Comment: `Rename-Item -NewName "newname.txt"`, no need to use the existing `Name` for anything

Comment: PS C:\> rename-item -path c:\docs\dump.csv -newname Report.xls - you could follow that renaming process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use it, but all filter files will be renamed to "newname.txt":

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\logsTop1\*.txt | Rename-Item -NewName {"newname.txt"}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your statement replaces the *extension* of the filename with `newname.txt`, effectively appending `newname.txt` to the file's basename. To rename the file to `newname.txt` just specify that as the new name:

```
Get-Childitem -Path C:\logsTop1\*.txt | Rename-Item -NewName 'newname.txt'
```